# Cannot POST /contact - but no where in my code do I request that post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer

I'm trying to create a contact box with nodemailer and everything worked at first. I console.logged(error) or "success" and received the email where it was supposed to go and also received my console "success" message. However, when I go to render a physical "success" message that the user can see, I receive the error cannot POST /contact. The weird thing is I don't have the post request going to /contact. I've been looking at the code for a while so it could be something simple, but I'm at a loss. I appreciate any help.

I've tried to render the homepage, declared a variable and put that variable onto the webpage to display for the user then I just tried displaying the home page and still receiving the same error. *I've left some critical information blank as I'm doing this on my local system before I push it to Heroku.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: '',
      pass: ''
    }
  });

  mailOpts = {
    from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
    to: '',
    subject: 'New message from contact form',
    text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email} ${req.body.nbr}) says: ${req.body.msg}`
  };
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      res.render('/');
    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: **res.render('/')** is wrong, argument to render() is always a view specified by an absolute path with name and extension or a relative one, but AFAIK a name should always be specified

Answer (score 0):

Change `/` to `/contact`:

```
app.post('/contact', function(req, res) {...});
```